# Extra Keyboard Shortcuts for Porportional Editing?

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut, customization

It's nice to enable/disable proportional editing with O, but I'd like to switch between falloff settings with a keyboard shortcut. If I open the the menu and right click on an option, the "Assign Shortcut" option *is* there, but blender doesn't seem to be able to differentiate between the different modes if I assign different shortcuts:

[image]

Is there any way to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the falloff pie menu meet your requirement?

It should be <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> by default:

[image]

You can search the shortcut in preference with keyword `falloff`:

[image]